# Local transform gizmo isn't visually matching the selected object. Is this a bug?

Tags: workflow, selection-tools, transform-orientation

Is this a bug?

Whenever I have to move around many objects with individual orientations and move them in local mode and dragselecting with box/circle/laso, the object only stays orange and the transform gizmo keeps the orientations of the "active" (yellow) object. But when I grab and move an axis it moves correctly according to the object local orientation.

[image]